# Linking error with 3rd party library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, c, linker, opus

I need to decode pcm data to opus format.
Therefore I want to include the opus source into my project, but I can't link the files.
I downloaded the source file `opus-1.1.tar.gz` from [here](http://opus-codec.org/downloads/).
In Qt Creator, I added all the files to my `pro`-file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
$$PWD/opus/opus/celt \
$$PWD/opus/opus/celt/arm \
$$PWD/opus/opus/celt/tests \
$$PWD/opus/opus/celt/x86 \
$$PWD/opus/opus/silk \
$$PWD/opus/opus/silk/arm \
$$PWD/opus/opus/silk/fixed \
$$PWD/opus/opus/silk/float \
$$PWD/opus/opus/include \
$$PWD/opus/opus/win32

// and here would come an abnormous listing of all c- and h-files of opus:
SOURCES += ... 
HEADERS += ...
```

At compile time, I get a warning from `stack_alloc.h`

```
#if (!defined (VAR_ARRAYS) && !defined (USE_ALLOCA) && !defined (NONTHREADSAFE_PSEUDOSTACK))
#error "Opus requires one of VAR_ARRAYS, USE_ALLOCA, or NONTHREADSAFE_PSEUDOSTACK be defined to select the temporary allocation mode."
#endif
```

For example, `USE_ALLOCA` is defined in `config.h` in `opus/win32`. From what I've seen, the file `config.h` only gets included like this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif
```

But in none of the files shipped with the source I can find `#define HAVE_CONFIG_H`.
Moreover, in the file `config.h` there is a `#include "version.h"`. That file is also not delivered with the source. I really don't know how I can use the Opus-lib. This can't be that hard, but I do not find a running minimal example at all.

I am using Windows 8, mingw, and c++ but the library is c.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-D VAR_ARRAYS` to your compile command or define in a header file:

```
#define VAR_ARRAYS 1
```

When building with emscripten (WebAssembly), I had to add two following flags:

```
$ emcc -D VAR_ARRAYS -D OPUS_BUILD ...
```